# Compare two lists and verify that list value one contains lists two python

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter

I have two lists and would like to check if any value from the list one has a value on the list two, the list two (are given from twitter, so will be always different), already lists a fixed then it is not modified.You would then check if any value in the list has the list two and create a rank for the words from the list two more appear.

## LIST ONE

```
track_lista = ['iPhone 6',
               'iPhone 5s',
               'iPhone 6 Plus',
               'iPhone 4s',
               'iPhone 5',
               'iPhone 5c',
               'iPhone 4',
               'Zenfone 2 ZE551ML',
               'Zenfone 5 A500CG',
               'Zenfone 2 Deluxe ZE551ML',
               'Zenfone Max ZC550KL',
               'Zenfone C ZC451CG',
               'Zenfone 2 Laser ZE500KL',
               'Zenfone 4',
               'Zenfone 2 ZE550ML',
               'Zenfone 6 A600CG',
               'Zenfone 2 Laser ZE601KL',
               'Zenfone Selfie ZD551KL',
               'Zenfone 2 Laser ZE550KL]
```

## LIST TWO

```
myTweet = ['rt @terranoticiasb: sortearemos esse iphone 5s as 18:00 hrs. pra concorrer basta se inscrever no canal http://t.co/ywnycwfx2o boa sorte! ht…', 'gente ninguém conseguiu ai colocar as lentes do snap no iphone 4s? :']

__author__ = 'Lucas'
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pymongo import MongoClient
from modelos_Celular import track_lista


client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['twitter_db']
collection = db['twitter_collection']

copia_banco = collection.find()

for tweet in copia_banco:
    try:
        myTweet = (tweet['text']).lower()
        print(myTweet)
    except:
    continue
```

Comment: You are missing a `'` character at the end of list one, before closing bracket.